# Android close current activity and return to previous activity

Tags: android

In my second activity, I can uninstall an app after uninstall finished, the second activity remains. But I need to go for previous activity after uninstall finished

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+packageInfo.packageName);
            Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
            startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Comment: Have you call finish() after start uninstallIntent ?

Comment: Yes I called but app stops

Comment: @BalaRaja even after uninstall your app still activity open?

Comment: @HareshChhelana, Raja is UN-installing another app

Comment: Which app you are uninstalling?

Comment: @Pehlaj,Then i think finish() will work?

Comment: When uninstall button clicked a popup opens for ok or cancel. After clicked ok then uninstall finished. Then I want to go previous activity.

Comment: Another app!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your first activity (FirstActivity.java)

**FirstActivity.java**

1. Use **startActivityForResult**(uninstallIntent, 1); //1 is REQUEST_CODE
2. After unintalling app, **FirstActivity.onActivityResult** will be automatically called, you can use this method to do something.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == 1) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // un-installed successfully
           finish();
       }
       else {
           // failed to un-install
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please Explain with some detail

Comment: I am updating answer in a while

Comment: Yes, finish will work, please see the updated answer.